How frequently is random number generated when plotting function containing RandomReal?
Plot[Sin[x + 0.1*RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]


Plot[Sin[x + 0.1*RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 2]


I tried Reap to find all the data but from the plot it looks like the frequency is not constant.
data = Reap[Plot[Sin[x + 0.1*RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 2, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, Sin[x + 0.1*RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}]]}]]][[2, 1]];
interpFunc = Interpolation[data];
ListLinePlot[Table[{x, interpFunc[x]}, {x, 0.001, 0.5, 0.001}]]



Most likely, every time Plot evaluates the expression to sample it. The rate at which Plot does that probably depends on, among other things, how not smooth the function looks, so left to its own devices Plot will likely end up evaluating it a couple of times ~~for every horizontal pixel it expects to draw~~ (apparently not).

Is there some practical reason why plotting such a model (Sin[x + 0.1*RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}]]) makes any sense in the first place?

The random number is the phase noise of a clock system, e.g. phase-locked loop, a major design concern in the sysem design.@JimB

Thanks. My issue isn’t with the model but rather that your plot command is not an appropriate way to describe the model.

I should have said "your plot command is not an appropriate way to display the model."

I'm going to argue that attempting to plot the model
$$y=x+0.1 \sin(z)$$
where $z\sim U[0,2\pi]$ using Plot for all values of $x$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ with the following code
Plot[Sin[x + 0.1*RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]

is nonsense and knowing how frequently a random value of $z$ is generated in Plot is irrelevant and uninformative.
What does make sense?  Suppose you have a finite number of $x$ values and you want to plot the values of a particular set of realizations of $y$ assuming that the values of $z$ are all independent.  Then one could do the following:
SeedRandom[12345];
x = Range[0, 2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/10];
z = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 2 \[Pi]}], Length[x]];
ListPlot[Transpose[{x, Sin[x + 0.1  z]}]]


If one wanted a 100% prediction band for the model, the following can be used:
x =.;
z =.;
min[x_] := Minimize[{Sin[x + 0.1 z], 0 <= z <= 2 \[Pi]}, z][[1]]
max[x_] := Maximize[{Sin[x + 0.1 z], 0 <= z <= 2 \[Pi]}, z][[1]]
Plot[{min[x], max[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, PlotStyle -> Black]



MaxRecursion looks to be the main thing affecting sampling rate:
f[r_] := Length[Reap[Plot[Sin[x + 0.1 Sow[RandomReal[{0, 2 π}]]],
                           {x, 0, 2 π}, MaxRecursion -> r]][[2, 1]]];
Table[f[i],{i,1,8}]


{102, 200, 396, 788, 1541, 3125, 6270, 12496}

With some random variation, especially for the higher recursion levels.
Sow is wrapped around RandomReal here so that every time RandomReal is called it will be sowed for Reap later, so it provides an accurate count of how many times RandomReal is sampled. It looks (looking at the plots) unlikely that Plot reuses any values of RandomReal other than through interpolation, so each sampling point should get its own evaluation of RandomReal.
A similar test can be performed with other plot options: ImageSize has no impact at all, Mesh does not have an impact either, PerformanceGoal does though (about the same as setting MaxRecursion -> 1 for "Speed" and MaxRecursion->6 for "Quality").

Not sure what last OP's image should represent but sampling is evenly distributed on interval (0, 2 Pi) as can be seen on the last image. Function was called 3130 times.
n = 0; xx = {};
f[x_] := (n++; AppendTo[xx, {n, x}]; 
  Sin[x + 0.1*RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}]])
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
n
ListPlot[xx]

Clear[n, xx, f]



